# No Argument Decorator Decorator?

Tags: python

I wrote a decorator that looks like this

```
def login_required_message(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('message', "You must be logged in to do that.")
    return _user_passes_test_message(lambda u: u.is_authenticated(), *args, **kwargs)
```

But when I try to use it without the `()` at the end, it fails, unless I rewrite it like this:

```
def login_required_message(function=None, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('message', "You must be logged in to do that.")
    decorator = _user_passes_test_message(lambda u: u.is_authenticated(), *args, **kwargs)
    if function: return decorator(function)
    else: return decorator
```

Then the `()` is optional. So, how do I encapsulate this "optional" functionality into a decorator so that I can decorate my decorators to allow no arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually recently wrote a [blog post](http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2010/08/more-python-voodoo-optional-argument-decorators.html) about this - at least, I *think* it addresses what you're trying to do. For posterity, here's what I came up with:

```
def opt_arguments(func):
    def meta_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) == 1 and callable(args[0]):
            return func(args[0])
        else:
            def meta_func(inner_func):
                return func(inner_func, *args, **kwargs)
            return meta_func
    return meta_wrapper
```

By the way, in the process of trying to figure out how to do it, I came to the conclusion that this is one of those things that is almost always more complication than necessary ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired by recipe 9.6 of the Python Cookbook

```
def mydecorator_with_opt_args(func=None, arg1="arg1-default", arg2="arg2-default"):
    if func is None:
        return partial(mydecorator_with_opt_args, arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Do something with {arg1} and {arg2}")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

To use it :

```
@mydecorator_with_opt_args(arg1="arg1-set", arg2="arg2-set")
def passer():
    pass
passer()
```

will output

```
"Do something with arg1-set and arg2-set"

@mydecorator_with_opt_args
def passer2():
    pass
passer2()
```

will output

```
"Do something with arg1-default and arg2-default"
```

To understand what happens if you specify no args (passer2):
Putting a decorator is the same as writing  `passer2 = mydecorator_with_opt_args(passer2)` which means the `if func is None` is ignored and you apply the decorator with the default arguments

However if you specify args (passer), Putting a decorator is the same as writing `passer = mydecorator_with_opt_args(arg1="arg1-set", arg2="arg2-set")(passer)`

`mydecorator_with_opt_args(arg1="arg1-set", arg2="arg2-set")` returns `partial(mydecorator_with_opt_args, arg1="arg1-set", arg2="arg2-set")` and then `partial(mydecorator_with_opt_args, arg1="arg1-set", arg2="arg2-set")(passer)` is equivalent to `mydecorator_with_opt_args(func=passer, arg1="arg1-set", arg2="arg2-set")`

Note that you need to specify the keyword arguments.